# getLastKnownLocation always returning null. Please explain?

Tags: android, google-maps-api-3, location

Could you please explain why getLastKnownLocation always returns null?

**This is the onCreate method :**

```
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    locationManager = (LocationManager) getSystemService(Context.LOCATION_SERVICE);

    provider = locationManager.getBestProvider(new Criteria(), false);

    if (ActivityCompat.checkSelfPermission(this, Manifest.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION) != PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED && ActivityCompat.checkSelfPermission(this, Manifest.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION) != PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {
        // TODO: Consider calling
        //    ActivityCompat#requestPermissions
        // here to request the missing permissions, and then overriding
        //   public void onRequestPermissionsResult(int requestCode, String[] permissions,
        //                                          int[] grantResults)
        // to handle the case where the user grants the permission. See the documentation
        // for ActivityCompat#requestPermissions for more details.
        return;
    }

    locationManager.requestLocationUpdates(provider, 400, 1, this);

    Location location = locationManager.getLastKnownLocation(provider);

    if (location != null) {
        Log.i("Location info", "location achieved");
    } else
        Log.i("Location info", "location failed");


}
```

**Logs show this :**

```
04-25 19:13:03.437 11755-11755/com.example.saurabh.locationdemo E/MultiWindowProxy: getServiceInstance failed!

04-25 19:13:03.462 11755-11755/com.example.saurabh.locationdemo I/Location info: location failed
```

***I am testing the app on my device and have enabled Google location on the device.***

Comment: The issue is with the getSystemService line (I have the same issue), but don't know how to resolve it.

Answer (score 1):

I had the same issue, no lat lng showing, and I was getting the same message:

> E/MultiWindowProxy: getServiceInstance failed!

What solved it for me was to go to my smartphone's `Settings`, `Apps` sub-menu, and there find my app. Then go to the permissions and manually allow to give my location.

Answer (score -2):

Okay, please see below code which I use in a number of apps (and works well) which should set you in the right direction. Today is the first time I've posted an answer on StackOverflow so please don't flame me if I have not explained enough, hopefully the code will be self-explanatory?

```
 public boolean getLocation(Context context, LocationResult result)
{

    locationResult=result;
    if(lm==null)
        lm = (LocationManager) context.getSystemService(Context.LOCATION_SERVICE);

try{gps_enabled=lm.isProviderEnabled(LocationManager.GPS_PROVIDER);}catch(Exception ex){}
    try{network_enabled=lm.isProviderEnabled(LocationManager.NETWORK_PROVIDER);}catch(Exception ex){}

    if(!gps_enabled && !network_enabled)
        return false;

    if(gps_enabled)
        lm.requestLocationUpdates(LocationManager.GPS_PROVIDER, 0, 0, locationListenerGps);
    if(network_enabled)
        lm.requestLocationUpdates(LocationManager.NETWORK_PROVIDER, 0, 0, locationListenerNetwork);
    timer1=new Timer();


    timer1.schedule(new GetLastLocation(), 10000);
    return true;
}

LocationListener locationListenerGps = new LocationListener() {
    public void onLocationChanged(Location location) {
        timer1.cancel();
        locationResult.gotLocation(location);
        lm.removeUpdates(this);
        lm.removeUpdates(locationListenerNetwork);
    }
    public void onProviderDisabled(String provider) {}
    public void onProviderEnabled(String provider) {}
    public void onStatusChanged(String provider, int status, Bundle extras) {}
};

LocationListener locationListenerNetwork = new LocationListener() {
    public void onLocationChanged(Location location) {
        timer1.cancel();
        locationResult.gotLocation(location);
        lm.removeUpdates(this);
        lm.removeUpdates(locationListenerGps);
    }
    public void onProviderDisabled(String provider) {}
    public void onProviderEnabled(String provider) {}
    public void onStatusChanged(String provider, int status, Bundle extras) {}
};

class GetLastLocation extends TimerTask {
    @Override

    public void run() {


         Location net_loc=null, gps_loc=null;
         if(gps_enabled)
             gps_loc=lm.getLastKnownLocation(LocationManager.GPS_PROVIDER);
         if(network_enabled)
             net_loc=lm.getLastKnownLocation(LocationManager.NETWORK_PROVIDER);

         if(gps_loc!=null && net_loc!=null){
             if(gps_loc.getTime()>net_loc.getTime())
                 locationResult.gotLocation(gps_loc);
             else
                 locationResult.gotLocation(net_loc);
             return;
         }

         if(gps_loc!=null){
             locationResult.gotLocation(gps_loc);
             return;
         }
         if(net_loc!=null){
             locationResult.gotLocation(net_loc);
             return;
         }
         //locationResult.gotLocation(null);
    }
}
```

Comment: Can you expand on why this proposed solution resolves the OP?